# Incorrect navigation with back button in browser while navigating across two React-Router applications

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have two React applications that I am navigating across with setups like this:

```
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes ... />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

When I am logged in, we navigate to localhost:3000/dashboard.

A sub route in the dashboard (we'll call it  localhost:3000/showcase) redirects to a different application we use that uses a similar react-router setup (localhost:3001/different-site).

When I press the back button the browser, the only route I can actually navigate back to is the localhost:3000/dashboard page, although I just navigated from localhost:3000/showcase.

Is there a more proper way of doing the history here?

Comment: If it redirects to a different application entirely, it's possible that the history stack got overwritten. You'd have to maintain the previous history to ensure you could go back to the previous application.

Comment: Like in localstorage or in our database?

Comment: Yes probably using that. Let the second app import from localstorage if it exists perhaps